# Solving an equation with Laplace operator for a specific solution in spherical and polar coordinates

Tags: waves, coordinate-systems, mathematics, differential-equations, eigenvalue

I am trying to solve an eigenvalue problem related to Laplace operator. I want to find a specific solution that only depends on the radial coordinate $r$ to the equation

$$\nabla^2 \psi = -k^2 \psi$$

In spherical coordinates ($r, \theta, \phi$) the solution I want is

$$\psi(r) = \frac{e^{i k r}}{r}$$

and it is easy to prove it is a solution of the above problem. However, I am having an hard time to find an equivalent solution in polar coordinates ($r, \theta, z$)! I tried for example something like

$$\psi(r) = \frac{e^{i k r}}{r^n}$$

and set as my goal to find the value of $n$ that would solve the above equation in polar coordinates. I could not find any value of $n$ for that. Other than that I have no idea how to find a solution to that problem in polar coordinates.

However, I keep thinking such a solution exists. Because in spherical coordinates if you multiply the above solution by $e^{-i\omega t}$ you see that it corresponds to a spherical wave propagating from the origin and attenuating with a factor $1/r$. I would be tempted to think that in polar coordinates something similar would happen, but with a factor $1/\sqrt{r}$.

Can you help and clarify what would it be the term that should be multiplied by $e^{i k r}$ so that it solves the equation in polar coordinates?

Comment: Shouldn't you get [Bessel functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html) for this Helmholtz equation in cylindrical-polar?

Comment: Also this isn't a question about physics, you'd likely get a better response at [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The solution in cylindrical polar coördinates $(\varrho,\varphi,z)$ is just not looking like what you wrote down. You could have seen that it is not going to work, by seeing that the spherical wave situation does not have other powers in the denominator except one. Nonetheless, it is doomed to be weird because the $z$ dependence and $\varrho$ dependence are intertwined, and so you ought to have at least a series, if not an integral, with a free parameter for every $k$. I wonder if $e^{ik\sqrt{\varrho^2+z^2}}/\sqrt{\varrho^2+z^2}$ works

Comment: @HVAC I saw the link you sent. Thanks. Are you saying that the solution in 2D is the Hankel function H_0(r)? If so, how is this related to the wave. I mean, if I multiply it by $e^{i \omega t}$ that is not a wave, right?

Comment: See:(the link between Bessel, Hankel and  Newman functions ....)  https://archive.org/details/smirnov-a-course-of-higher-mathematics-vol-3-2-complex-variables-special-functions/Smirnov%20-%20A%20Course%20of%20Higher%20Mathematics%20-%20Vol%203-2%20-%20Complex%20Variables%20Special%20Functions/page/577/mode/1up?view=theater

Comment: And also: https://archive.org/details/smirnov-a-course-of-higher-mathematics-vol-2-advanced-calculus/Smirnov%20-%20A%20Course%20of%20Higher%20Mathematics%20-%20Vol%202%20-%20Advanced%20Calculus/page/524/mode/1up?view=theater

Comment: @HVAC I read your links and could not get it. It kind of points me to the fact that the Hankel functions correspond to solutions that are waves but apparently this is only true if you go very far away from the point source. I was expecting something simpler, because in 2D plane I can imagine a wave radiating away from a point. In my mind it would be of the form $e^{ikr}$. But apparently such a thing does not exist. It does not make sense to me... anyway... thanks.

Comment: In the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function, we read:... These forms of linear combination satisfy numerous simple-looking properties, like asymptotic formulae or integral representations. Here, "simple" means an appearance of a factor of the form $e^{i f(x)}.$ For real .....
The Hankel functions are used to express outward- and inward-propagating cylindrical-wave solutions of the cylindrical wave equation, respectively (or vice versa, depending on the sign convention for the frequency).

Comment: Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation   , "This is the Helmholtz equation and can be solved using separation of variables. If spherical coordinates are used to describe a problem, then the solution to the angular part of the Helmholtz equation is given by spherical harmonics, and the radial equation now becomes..."...,where $h_{l}^{(1)}(kr)$ and $h_{(l)}^{(2)}(kr)$
 are the spherical Hankel functions.

Comment: So you find in the previous link, the solution $ u(r)e^{i\omega t}=\frac{e^{\pm ikr}}{r}e^{i\omega t}=\frac{e^{i(\omega t\pm kr)}}{r}$, with $A=1$

Comment: @HVAC Sorry to insist, but the solution you say in your last post is valid in spherical coordinates, as you mention too. I am aware of that solution. Actually it is written in my question. But I was looking for the 2D version of that solution. And that is not a solution in 2D because if you use polar cylindrical coordinates that does not work.

Comment: My question can be stated as this too: in a 2D plane, what is the solution to Helmholtz equation for a point source at the origin of the form $e^{j \omega t }$